# I would want to rescale my image in all directions in my canvas, but it does only towards bottom-right corner

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

## Context

I have a canvas in which I draw an image. I would want to animate it: the image should be zoomed-in (rescaled) in all directions (vertical and horizontal expansions, towards the top, right, bottom, and left sides, all together and at the same time).

## Expected results

At each iteration, the image goes x pixels towards the top and the bottom, the left, and the right sides of the canvas: it's a zoom. The pixels of the image that go beyond the canvas become not visible.

## Actual results

At each iteration, the image goes x pixels towards the bottom and right sides of the canvas: it's a zoom. The pixels of the image that go beyond the canvas become not visible.

## The problem

The image goes x pixels towards the bottom and right sides of the canvas instead of going x pixels towards the top and the bottom, the left, and the right sides of the canvas.

## The question

How to make the image go x pixels towards the top and the bottom, the left, and the right sides of the canvas?

## Minimal and Testable Example

### How to test my example?

1. Download an image file titled "my_img.jpg", store it in a directory titled "my_dir". You can change the names; think to change them in the below source code too (line to be changed:  `var images = [ ....`).
2. In this same directory, store my code in a file titled "index.HTML"
3. Open your browser to read "index.HTML"
4. Click on the "Start" button, the animation will begin and you will see my problem.

### Sources

#### Comments

Note the use of `ctx.drawImage(tmp_canvas, -(tmp_canvas.width - canvas.width)/2, -(tmp_canvas.height - canvas.height)/2);`, which is censed to draw the zoomed image (from a new canvas named "tmp_canvas"), in the real canvas (whose context is `ctx`). I divide by 2 the difference between the zoomed image minus the real canvas, which normally corresponds to the fact to draw the zoomed image expanded towards left AND right. The same techniqye is used for top and bottom sides.

#### Clues

`console.log(-(tmp_canvas.width - canvas.width)/2);` shows 0, it should not. `tmp_canvas.width` should be the zoomed image's width. `canvas.width` should be the canvas' width.

#### index.HTML

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Creating Final Video</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button id="start">Start</button>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="3200" height="1608"></canvas>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      var images = ["my_dir/my_img.jpg"];

      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      var img = new Image();

      function showSomeMedia() {
        setImageListener();
        setImageSrc();
      }

      function setImageSrc() {
        img.src = images[0];
        img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
      }

      function imgOnLoad() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.restore();

        var tmp_canvas = canvas.cloneNode();
        var tmp_ctx = tmp_canvas.getContext("2d");

        function zoomInCanvas() {
          tmp_ctx.scale(1.001, 1.001);

          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          ctx.drawImage(
            tmp_canvas,
            -(tmp_canvas.width - canvas.width) / 2,
            -(tmp_canvas.height - canvas.height) / 2
          );
        }

        var i = 0;
        const interval = setInterval(function() {
          if (i == 100) {
            clearInterval(interval);
          }

          tmp_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, tmp_canvas.width, tmp_canvas.height);
          tmp_ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
          requestAnimationFrame(zoomInCanvas);

          i++;
        }, 1000);
      }

      function setImageListener() {
        img.onload = function() {
          imgOnLoad();
        };
      }

      $("#start").click(function() {
        showSomeMedia();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about how to solve some of the other problems with your code, however I can help with being able to rescale images in all directions.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#resizable').resizable({
    handles: 'n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw, nw'
});
});
```

```css
#resizable {
    width: 50%;   
    border: 1px solid black;   
}

#resizable img {
    width: 100%;   
}

.ui-resizable-handle {
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    
    z-index: 2;
}

.ui-resizable-se {
    right: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
}

#resizable { 
  width: 150px; 
  height: 150px; 
  padding: 0.5em; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<img id="resizable" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
```

Some of this code is from a question that I recently asked, and got an answer for.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the `translate` call doesn't change the `tmp_canvas`'s image's dimensions. So I have to compute these new width and height and store them in parralel. The following code works perfectly:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Creating Final Video</title>
</head>

<body>
<button id="start">Start</button>

<canvas id="canvas" width=3200 height=1608></canvas>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var images = [
    'my_dir/my_img.jpg'
];

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();

function showSomeMedia() {
    setImageListener();
    setImageSrc();
}

function setImageSrc() {
    img.src = images[0];
    img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
}

function imgOnLoad() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.restore();

    var tmp_canvas = canvas.cloneNode();
    var tmp_ctx = tmp_canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img_new_width = tmp_canvas.width;
    var img_new_height = tmp_canvas.height;

    function zoomInCanvas() {
        img_new_width *= 1.001
        img_new_height *= 1.001
        tmp_ctx.scale(1.001, 1.001);

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(tmp_canvas, -(img_new_width - canvas.width)/2, -(img_new_height - canvas.height)/2);
    }

    var i = 0;
    const interval = setInterval(function() {
            if(i == 100) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }

            tmp_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, tmp_canvas.width, tmp_canvas.height);
            tmp_ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
            requestAnimationFrame(zoomInCanvas);

            i++;
      }, 1000);
}

function setImageListener() {
    img.onload = function () {
       imgOnLoad();
    };
}

$('#start').click(function() {
    showSomeMedia();
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```